# Set Tomcat <Context> param from deployed Eclipse web application

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, tomcat, dwr

I have an Eclipse Java web application that I am deploying to Tomcat 7 from within Eclipse 3.7.  In my Eclipse server configuration at `Servers > Tomcatv7-config > server.xml`, I see the following line is added when I deploy my application:

```
<Context docBase="myapp" path="/myapp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:myapp"/>
```

My question is this: is there any way for me to add a parameter to this `<Context>` element for a specific project?

What I need to do is add `useHttpOnly=”false”` in order for [DWR to work properly in Tomcat 7](http://dwr.2114559.n2.nabble.com/DWR-CSRF-Security-Error-with-HttpOnly-cookies-tc4550130.html#a4550210).  I understand the security risks with this, so please no lecture :)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to specify a context.xml in /META-INF/ within your WAR/Project which will trump the server.xml line:

> In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application
>   files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute) this may be
>   copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to
>   application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I don't like the idea of my app deciding where to deploy itself to (which is part of the <Context> node).  It seems like that should be controlled by the deployer, not the application.  Also, our code is shipped to customers, so I can't really put a hard-coded context.xml in our app (although I suppose I could exclude it from the build process, of course).  Even with this concerns, do you think this is the only way to achieve what I need?  Thanks!